# Like query not working when using [ or ] in like

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, search, sql-like

Need to ask about strange behaviour of SQL Server 2005.

What I need is to find records that contain ']' or '[' in my column

I have a data in column like this

```
'6b51c65b-5773-415a-aec9-8482c404faef_megas_xlr[1].jpg'
```

When I run this query

```
select * from Theme  where BackgroundImageUrl like '%[%'
```

then no records comes up, but running this below query

```
select * from Theme  where BackgroundImageUrl like '%]%'
```

boils following output

```
'6b51c65b-5773-415a-aec9-8482c404faef_megas_xlr[1].jpg'
```

What's wrong in that query?  What do I need to do in order to search records having closing or starting brackets `[]`?

EDIT..

For more clarification, here is my test data.
A[1].jpg
B[1.jpg
C1].jpg

And below are  results  that I got after running following combination

A `select BackgroundImageUrl from Theme  where BackgroundImageUrl like '%[%'`

No Results

B `select BackgroundImageUrl from Theme  where BackgroundImageUrl like '%]%'`

A[1].jpg
C1].jpg

C `select BackgroundImageUrl from Theme  where BackgroundImageUrl like '%[ [ ]%'`

A[1].jpg
B[1.jpg

D `select BackgroundImageUrl from Theme  where BackgroundImageUrl like '%[ ] ]%'`

No Results

What I need is that,
Case 1 : I need all records that contains '['

Case2 : I need all records that contains ']'

Query  C fulfills my case 1 but I m not able to get result for my case 2

Comment: So you want filenames with only a [ OR a ]?

Comment: yup, sometimes i only need to fetch [ and sometime only with ]

Comment: Does my edit reflect what you need? If not, could please post some exampleS?

Comment: What do you mean "sometimes"? I assume that with a condition that you haven't bothered telling us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i just discovered my answer.

```
select * from Theme  where BackgroundImageUrl like  '%\]%' ESCAPE '\'
```

and

```
select * from Theme  where BackgroundImageUrl like  '%\[%' ESCAPE '\'
```

Answer (score 3):

[] are an explicit part of the wild card search:

Wildcard character  Description  Example
**%**
 Any string of zero or more characters.
 WHERE title LIKE '%computer%' finds all book titles with the word 'computer' anywhere in the book title.

**_** (underscore)
 Any single character.
 WHERE au_fname LIKE '_ean' finds all four-letter first names that end with ean (Dean, Sean, and so on).

**[ ]**
 Any single character within the specified range ([a-f]) or set ([abcdef]).
 WHERE au_lname LIKE '[C-P]arsen' finds author last names ending with arsen and starting with any single character between C and P, for example Carsen, Larsen, Karsen, and so on. In range searches, the characters included in the range may vary depending on the sorting rules of the collation.

**[^]**
 Any single character not within the specified range ([^a-f]) or set ([^abcdef]).
 WHERE au_lname LIKE 'de[^l]%' all author last names starting with de and where the following letter is not l.

you need to apply an escape clause to have SQL Server evaluate [] as what you are searching for:

```
match_expression [ NOT ] LIKE pattern [ ESCAPE escape_character ]
```

*escape_character*
Is a character that is put in front of a wildcard character to indicate that the wildcard should be interpreted as a regular character and not as a wildcard. escape_character is a character expression that has no default and must evaluate to only one character.

or you can use:
**Using Wildcard Characters As Literals**
You can use the wildcard pattern matching characters as literal characters. To use a wildcard character as a literal character, enclose the wildcard character in brackets. The following table shows several examples of using the LIKE keyword and the [ ] wildcard characters.

```
Symbol           Meaning  
---------------  --------------------
LIKE '5[%]'      5%
LIKE '[_]n'      _n
LIKE '[a-cdf]'   a, b, c, d, or f
LIKE '[-acdf]'   -, a, c, d, or f
LIKE '[ [ ]'     [
LIKE ']'         ]
LIKE 'abc[_]d%'  abc_d and abc_de
LIKE 'abc[def]'  abcd, abce, and abcf
```

Answer (score 0):

[LIKE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)

`[]` is used to identify ranges in a LIKE-clause.

The documentation linked above has following solution:

> Using Wildcard Characters As Literals
>
> You can use the wildcard pattern matching characters as literal
>   characters. To use a wildcard character as a literal character,
>   enclose the wildcard character in brackets. The following table shows
>   several examples of using the LIKE keyword and the [ ] wildcard
>   characters.

```
Symbol       | Meaning
LIKE '[ [ ]' | [
LIKE ']'     | ]
```

Your query would have to look like this:

```
select * from Theme  where BackgroundImageUrl like '%[ [ ]%'
```

**Edit**: Assuming you only want files that either have a [ OR a ], but not both:

```
select * from Theme  where (BackgroundImageURL like '%]%' AND BackgroundImageURL  not like '%[[]%')  or (BackgroundImageURL  like '%[[]%' AND BackgroundImageURL  not like '%]%')
```

Comment: sorry, in this case, it is bringing records with spaces to and some of the records which dont  have [ at all =(

Comment: The spaces in `'%[ [ ]%'` are undoubtedly added for clarity, remove them in the real query.

Answer (score 0):

From here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

Get the rows containing [ or ] like this.

```
declare @T table (S varchar(100))

insert into @T values ('A[1].jpg')
insert into @T values ('B[1.jpg')
insert into @T values ('C1].jpg')

select *
from @T
where S like '%[[]%' or
      S like '%]%'
```

Result;

```
S
---------
A[1].jpg
B[1.jpg
C1].jpg
```

Comment: yes i know that but its bringing both records having [ or ] , i need to pick [ and sometimes only with ]

Comment: this is becouse you dont have any records containing ]

Comment: @Singleton – Think I know what you want now. You can do this with two `like` statements in the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the opening bracket:

```
LIKE '%[[]%
```

but you don't have to escape the closing one (as you noted)

The rest of the "sometimes" logic is up to you. Or a new, *complete*, question. We've answered this one.